# for aggressively repeated alarms, which is better Alarm or Service with Timer task?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am trying to do an application that shows the user notification with options that user can choose:

1. Aggressively repeated: like every 3 minutes (does not wake-lock the device)
2. Highly repeated: every 10 to 15 minutes (does not wake-lock the device)
3. Repeated: every 1 hour
4. once a day

so for the first 3 options, (as a Performance and battery life) is it good solution to set up  Timer and start a scheduleTimerTask within **Service** ? or should i set an **Alarm** from **AlarmManager**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service**

1. Constantly runs in Background , will drain battery
2. Can be killed by android or user might go to setting and kill it manually
3. Will be killed if phone is switched off

> service was basically meant to do background services like loading and
>   uploading data on separate thread, for your purpose AlarmManager is
>   useful and it will not be killed by android and probably will drain
>   less juice than service

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use an alarm. A service can be killed by the OS.